# Jquery drag and drop elements stay in list and create another

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have lists of elements which may be drag and drop in `<div class="droppable">` . But after drop the draged element must stay in list. For example if I drag and drop `<p class="draggable" name="name">Name</p`> it will be stay in first div and will create in  `<div class="droppable">`

```
<div>
    <p class="draggable" name="name">Name</p>
    <p class="draggable" name="LastName">LastName</p>
    <p class="draggable" name="Country">Country</p>
</div>


<div class="droppable">
</div>


$(function() {
   $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
   });


   $('.droppable').droppable({
        accept: '.draggable',
         drop: function(){
            alert("HEY!");
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the Clone inside of the drop function to create a clone of the dragged element

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4hTM2/1/)**

```
 $(".draggable").draggable({
     helper: "clone"
 });

 $('.droppable').droppable({
     accept: '.draggable',
     drop: function (e, ui) {
         $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo($(this));
     }
 });
```